# Python Congressional Plotly TypeError: Object of type MultiPolygon is not JSON serializable for Congressional Districts

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, choropleth

```
import pandas as pd
from census import Census
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
pio.renderers.default='browser'

file_path = "Path"


# Load Census Median Age by District Data

c = Census("KEY")
district_df = c.acs1.state_congressional_district(['NAME', 'B01002_001E'], '*', '*')
district_df = pd.DataFrame(district_df)
district_df.rename(columns={'B01002_001E': 'median_age'},
                          inplace=True)
district_df['GEOID'] = district_df['state'] + district_df['congressional district']
district_df.sort_values(by=['GEOID'], ascending=True)
district_df['id'] = np.arange(1,438)


# Import District Geojson
geojson_path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CivilServiceUSA/us-house/master/us-house/geojson/us-house.geojson'
geojson_file = gpd.read_file(geojson_path)


# Transformations
# Fill at-large districts nans with 0 to align with census
geojson_file[['district']] = geojson_file[['district']].fillna(value=0)
geojson_file['district'] = geojson_file.district.astype(float)


# drop congressional districts that have no voting power (State Number 98)
district_df['congressional district'] = district_df['congressional district'].astype(float)
# district_df = district_df.loc[district_df['state'] != 98]

# Create index state_name to inner join
new = district_df['NAME'].str.split(", ", n = 1, expand = True)
district_df['district_name'] = new[0]
district_df['state_name'] = new[1]
district_df.drop(columns = 'NAME', inplace = True)

# Inner Join
merged_data = pd.merge(district_df, geojson_file,
                             left_on=['state_name', 'congressional district'],
                             right_on=['state_name', 'district'])
# Plot
fig = px.choropleth(merged_data,
                    geojson=merged_data.geometry,
                    locations=merged_data.index,
                    color='median_age',
                    color_continuous_scale='Viridis',
                    scope='usa',
                    projection='mercator',
                    basemap_visible=True)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
fig.update_layout(title_text='Map')

fig.show()
```

When I run this code, I get the following error

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/colby/Desktop/Colby's Folder/Congressional Demo ETL Project/scripts/etl.py", line 81, in <module>
    fig.show()

  File "/Users/colby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 3398, in show
    return pio.show(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/colby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/io/_renderers.py", line 404, in show
    renderers._perform_external_rendering(fig_dict, renderers_string=renderer, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/colby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/io/_renderers.py", line 341, in _perform_external_rendering
    renderer.render(fig_dict)

  File "/Users/colby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/io/_base_renderers.py", line 747, in render
    html = to_html(

  File "/Users/colby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/io/_html.py", line 141, in to_html
    jdata = to_json_plotly(fig_dict.get("data", []))

  File "/Users/colby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/io/_json.py", line 124, in to_json_plotly
    return json.dumps(plotly_object, cls=PlotlyJSONEncoder, **opts)

  File "/Users/colby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(

  File "/Users/colby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_plotly_utils/utils.py", line 59, in encode
    encoded_o = super(PlotlyJSONEncoder, self).encode(o)

  File "/Users/colby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

  File "/Users/colby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)

  File "/Users/colby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_plotly_utils/utils.py", line 136, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

  File "/Users/colby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

TypeError: Object of type MultiPolygon is not JSON serializable
```

Solutions that I have tried:

1: I have also tried using geojson=geometry and locations=index based on the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/)

2: I have taken out geojson as an argument (since it is included in the df), and named locations='congressional district'. This gives me a blank white plot in browser.

3: I even used the data for a Congressional District shp from the census but that did not work either. I suspect because I am not sure how to properly input the arguments with a gpd df.

Comment: Do you have sample data that you can release? If so, I think you can get quick answers from many respondents.

Comment: @r-beginners

The data that I am using is entirely public, the map data comes from the census (district_df) and the geojson_path comes from a public github repo. At this point I am trying to figure out why I am getting that error. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I saw your answer and understood that the information is public. Thank you for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- it's not clear to me if your *geojson* is valid. Given you are plotting US census data, may as well use US census mapping data https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html
- there is no need to merge **geopandas** data frame and **pandas** dataframe.  Just require a link between the two *GEOID*
- full solution below. (Need to define `KEY` to be your key) Pan and zoom are not great by default

```
import requests
import urllib
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from census import Census
import plotly.express as px

# get geometry data as a geopandas dataframe
# fmt: off
# https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html
src = [{"name": "counties", "suffix": ".shp", "url": "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_cd116_20m.zip",},]
data = {}
for s in src:
    f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(s["url"]).path.split("/")[-1])
    if not f.exists():
        r = requests.get(s["url"],stream=True,)
        with open(f, "wb") as fd: 
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128): fd.write(chunk)

    fz = ZipFile(f)
    fz.extractall(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem))

    data[s["name"]] = gpd.read_file(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem).joinpath([f.filename for f in fz.infolist() if Path(f.filename).suffix == s["suffix"]][0]))
gdf = pd.concat(data.values()).to_crs("EPSG:4326")
# fmt: on

# get census measures...
c = Census(KEY)
district_df = (
    pd.DataFrame(c.acs1.state_congressional_district(["NAME", "B01002_001E"], "*", "*"))
    .rename(columns={"B01002_001E": "median_age"})
    .assign(
        GEOID=lambda d: d.loc[:, ["state", "congressional district"]]
        .astype(str)
        .apply("".join, axis=1)
    )
)

# plot
fig = px.choropleth(
    district_df,
    geojson=gdf.set_index("GEOID").geometry,
    locations="GEOID",
    color="median_age",
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
    # scope="usa",
    projection="mercator",
    basemap_visible=True,
)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="geojson", visible=True)
fig.update_layout(title_text="Map")
```

#### mapbox

I prefer Mapbox. Data sourcing identical, **plotly** API very similar

```
px.choropleth_mapbox(
    district_df,
    geojson=gdf.set_index("GEOID").geometry,
    locations="GEOID",
    color="median_age",
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "zoom": 3,
        "center": {"lat": 39.50, "lon": -98.35},
    },
    title_text="Map",
)
```

[image]

#### original geojson

- this only partially works.  Some states are missing
- the geojson does not have an ability to directly build **FIPS**.  Hence source of state alpha2 code to numeric FIPS code

```
import requests
import urllib
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from census import Census
import plotly.express as px

res = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CivilServiceUSA/us-house/master/us-house/geojson/us-house.geojson")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(res.json())
df_fips = pd.read_html(
    "https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detail/?cid=nrcs143_013696"
)[0]
df_fips = df_fips.dropna().assign(
    FIPS=lambda d: d["FIPS"].apply(lambda x: str(int(x)).zfill(2))
)
gdf = gdf.merge(df_fips, left_on="state_code", right_on="Postal Code").assign(
    GEOID=lambda d: d.apply(lambda r: r["FIPS"] + str(r["district"]).zfill(2), axis=1)
)

# get census measures...
c = Census(KEY)
district_df = (
    pd.DataFrame(c.acs1.state_congressional_district(["NAME", "B01002_001E"], "*", "*"))
    .rename(columns={"B01002_001E": "median_age"})
    .assign(
        GEOID=lambda d: d.loc[:, ["state", "congressional district"]]
        .astype(str)
        .apply("".join, axis=1)
    )
)

# plot
px.choropleth_mapbox(
    district_df,
    geojson=gdf.set_index("GEOID").geometry,
    locations="GEOID",
    color="median_age",
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "zoom": 3,
        "center": {"lat": 39.50, "lon": -98.35},
    },
    title_text="Map",
)
```

Comment: How would I be able to test if my geojson data is valid? I ask because I'd like to apply this map with an R vs. D seats that is detailed in this dataset. From looking at the link, it appears valid to me based on other geojson file structures (it is also regularly updated). Thanks for your help!

Comment: have updated answer.  it's not fully working but gives you a start